# Pandas Import Error when converting Python script to .exe with Pyinstaller

Tags: pandas, pyinstaller, exe, importerror

I am currently trying to convert my Python script that automates an Excel task for my boss to an executable so that I can send it to him and he can use it without having Python installed. One of the libraries I used in the script is Pandas, and when I run the .exe after successfully building it, I get "failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: No module named pandas."

This is what I used to build the .exe:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py
```

Obviously I have Pandas installed on my machine and the script works perfectly fine when I run it normally, so I don't really know why I am getting this error especially since I thought the whole point of me converting the script to an executable was to get rid of the need for other packages to be installed.

I have read other articles on here about a similar error relating to numpy, but none of the other solutions have helped me. I have tried doing --hidden-import pandas while building the executable and downgrading pandas to an older version, both to no success.

Any suggestions with help!

Comment: Do you import pandas in the normal manner in the script?  `import pandas as pd`?

Comment: @Alexander yes I do